# Unit Testing a Controller method returns null

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm trying to learn Unit testing in .NET 6 by testing a controller function `GetProduct`. The problem is I get null returned in the variable `var product = await _productController.GetProduct(productId);`. As you can see in the picture below, the `Result` is ok but the `Value`, where the `ServiceResponse<Product>` was suppose to be is null.

[image]

Here is the controller function:

```
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProductService _productService;

    public ProductController(IProductService productService)
    {
        _productService = productService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{productId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<Product>>> GetProduct(int productId)
    {
        var result = await _productService.GetProductAsync(productId);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Here is the Test:

```
public class ProductControllerTest
{
    private readonly ProductController _productController;
    private readonly Mock<IProductService> _productService = new Mock<IProductService>();

    public ProductControllerTest()
    {
        _productController = new ProductController(_productService.Object);
    }    

    [Test]
    public async Task GetProducts_ReturnsProduct_IfProductExists()
    {
        //Arange
        var productId = 1;
        var prodData = new Product
        {
            Id = productId,
            Title = "null"            
        };
        var prductResponse = new ServiceResponse<Product>
        {
            Data = prodData,
            Success = true ,
            Message = ""
        };

        _productService.Setup(x => x.GetProductAsync(productId)).ReturnsAsync(prductResponse);

        //Act
        var product = await _productController.GetProduct(productId);

        //Assert
        Assert.That(product?.Value?.Data?.Id, Is.EqualTo(productId));
    }

}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, what happens if you first setup your `_productService` and then create a new instance of `_productController` in your test ? 
I feel like your setup is not working because you've already injected your object. But it should work as you wrote it.

Comment: @yguerin I get the same result with the product being null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is observed due to [overloaded operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1.op_implicit?view=aspnetcore-6.0) on `ActionResult<T>` class.

Since the method, OK(value) returns an instance of OKObjectResult and the return type of controller method is of type `ActionResult<ServiceResponse<Product>>` the returned OKObjectResult instance is wrapped in an instance of `ActionResult<T>` and is exposed by the `Result` property. Hence typecasting the Result property (as shown by @BennyM) to OKObjectResult works.

Please note that the assertion would have succeeded had the controller method returned the `ServiceResponse<Product>` directly without modifying the return type on controller's method.

While this explains the behavior, I personally feel there is a better way to test controllers. This [MSDN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0) explains about integration testing. One can effectively unit test all the dimensions of the controllers - authentication, validation, (de)serialization, etc - by mocking the immediate dependencies of the respective controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning with an Ok call in your controller you can add a cast to the unit test.

```
   var result = (await _productController.GetProduct(productId)).Result as OkObjectResult;
   Assert.IsNotNull(result);
   var returnedServiceResponse = result.Value as ServiceResponse<Product>;
   Assert.That(returnedServiceResponse ?.Data?.Id, Is.EqualTo(productId));
```

Also you don't have to use Actionresult. You can also just return your service response

```
   [HttpGet("{productId}")]
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<Product>> GetProduct(int productId)
    {
        var result = await _productService.GetProductAsync(productId);
        return result;
    }
```

This will also make the test a bit easier as no need to use the OkObjectResult.

Comment: The returnedServiceResponse should be `var returnedServiceResponse = result.Value as ServiceResponse<Product>;`. The rest now works. Thank you!